# VBS Invalid Query in Windows 10

Tags: vbscript, wmi

Why does the following VBS code work in Windows 7 but gives error on Windows 10:

```
strComputer="."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'notepad.exe'")
Wscript.Echo colProcesses.Count
```

The error I'm getting in Windows 10 is:

> test_2.vbs(4,1) SWbemObjectSet: Invalid query

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code runs just fine on my system(Using Win 7 though).

Comment: Yes it works in Windows 7 as I mentioned in my Question, but doesn't for Windows 10

Comment: Oh..I didn't notice :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use the below code. This should work

```
strQuery = "select * from win32_process where Name = " & """" & "Notepad.exe" & """"
strComputer="."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery)
Wscript.Echo colProcesses.Count
```

Comment: Yes that works, Perfect. As I'm still learning VBS could you please explain why a lot of `"` marks in `strQuery`.

Comment: Understood the `Notepad.exe` requires a double quote in Windows 10 like this `"Notepad.exe"` but works with single quote `'Notepad.exe'`. This is quite strange. If anyone has reasons for this please explain. THanks.

Comment: There is no need for the extra concatenation just remember to double the quotes for a literal quote in a string variable, like this: `strQuery = "select * from win32_process where Name = ""Notepad.exe"""`.

Comment: An explanation (in the answer, not in comments) would greatly improve the value of the answer.